# Regarding Yii and cassandra work

Tags: cassandra, yii

I wonder yii works with cassandra.
If anybody know how it work.
Please post link or some references.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your using a major PHP ORM with Yii, the real question is 'Does PDO have a driver that will work with cassandra?'

```
    http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/
```

If you're using Yii's native Active Record ORM, it only supports AR with (from their site):

Support for AR is limited by DBMS. Currently, only the following DBMS are supported:

```
MySQL 4.1 or later
PostgreSQL 7.3 or later
SQLite 2 and 3
Microsoft SQL Server 2000 or later
Oracle
```

If you want to use an application component other than db, or if you want to work with multiple databases using AR, you should override CActiveRecord::getDbConnection(). The CActiveRecord class is the base class for all AR classes.

Of course, ORMs are meant for use on **relational databases** so using something like cassandra, Mongodb, or Couchdb might not be best to sit under an ORM.

Otherwise, your question doesn't make much sense.  It's like asking 'does database work with my code'.

Comment: You think i can use phpcassa?